# How can i integrate AntiXSS library in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, shared-libraries

I need to integrate this library [AntiXSS](https://github.com/voku/anti-xss#antixss---library) with codeigniter, 
someone can tell me how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Its explained in `README.md`. Follow the steps and you can do it by your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run this code on the terminal in the project directory. "composer require voku/anti-xss"
2. Change composer autoload settings false to true in your config file.

   `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;`
3. Add this line to your `index.php` file.

   `include_once './vendor/autoload.php';`
4. Create library file as `AntiXSSLibrary.php` in the library folder.

--

```
<?php
use voku\helper\AntiXSS;

class AntiXSSLibrary {

    public $xss;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->xss = new AntiXSS();
    } 

    public function clear($data)
        {
            return $this->xss->xss_clean($data);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

5. Load library in your controller like this.

--

```
<?php  
class HomeController extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
$this->load->library('antixsslibrary');
} 
public function index()
{
$clean = $this->antixsslibrary->clear($data);
}
}
?>
```